# PHP / SQL Ban status not echoing

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

I made a Banned.php page so say a user get's banned they will redirect to banned.php page for as long as they are banned!

issue i'm having the `status` set's to `1` fine but the ban `Reason` won't echo out for that user

The SQL Table for `bans` has these tables `username` & `reason`

Code:

```
<?php 
        //Check if the user is banned
        $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
        $SQL -> execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $status = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
        if ($status == 1){
            $ban = $odb -> query("SELECT `reason` FROM `bans` WHERE `username` = '$username'") -> fetchColumn(0);
            if(empty($ban)){ $ban = "No reason given."; }
            $error = 'You are banned. Reason: '.htmlspecialchars($ban);
        }                           ?>
```

If you could perhaps assist i tried error_reporting but not avail on getting errors just won't show reason / grab from SQL

Comment: I see SQL injection and bad code structure here.

Comment: Please provide 1) The connection creation code; 2) The code that you used for error reporting; 3) The `CREATE TABLE` syntax.

Comment: I would also suggest the use of only one table, `users`, with the following structure: `user_id | username | banned | ban_reason`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT reason FROM bans WHERE username LIKE '$username' LIMIT 1";
$result = $odb->query($sql);
```

then `$ban = $result->fetchColumn();` or `$ban = $result->fetchColumn()[0];`

`$stmt` might be a less confusing variable name, hence `$sql` is often used for query-strings.

`fetchColumn()` at least works with `PDO`, while it is unlear which driver is used.

Answer (score 0):

### Example DB Table

*(Run code snippet to see as "formatted" table.)*

```html
<table border="1px solid black;">
  <tr>
    <td>UserID</td>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>Reason</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>51414</td>
    <td>FelixCrystal</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>System exploitation.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

### Example Code

```
$Server = "localhost";
$Username = "myDBUsername";
$Password = "myDBPassword";
$dbName = "myDBName";
$Connect = MySQLi_Connect($Server, $Username, $Password, $dbName);
$SQL = "SELECT Status,Reason FROM Users WHERE UserID='51414'";
$Result = MySQLi_Query($this->Link, $SQL);
// Maybe 'If ($Result->num_rows == 0)' would be better to avoid duplicate accounts (Which shouldn't happen for ID based tables anyways)
If ($Result->num_rows > 0) {
    While ($Row = $Result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $Status = $Row["Status"];
        $Reason = $Row["Reason"];
    }
    If ($Status == 0 /* Or whatever your 'banned' value is */) {
        Header("Location: https://www.example.com/MyBannedPage.php?Reason=$Reason");
        /*
            I used a GET request for this example. You can use anything you'd like such as GET, POST, Sessions, Cookies, etc.
        */
    } Else {
        // Account is active!
    }
} Else {
    Echo "Error looking up account.";
}
```

### MyBannedPage.php

```
<?php
    If (Isset($_GET["Reason"])) {
        $Reason = $_GET["Reason"];
    } Else {
        $Reason = "Banned reason not supplied.";
    }
    Echo "Your account has been banned. Reason: $Reason";
?>
```

Comment: Actually, he's using the PDO extension.

Comment: @dakis, Yes, I realized thank you. This was more to show the logic and option for retrieval. It can be converted to PDO fairly easily.

Comment: The coding style is quite weird. Advised to use lowercase GET/POST parameters, reserved keywords & function names. Also, for URL, it's better to use lowercase (in Linux servers, uppercase URL is different from lowercase URL). Last, `UserID` is probably an integer, no need to use single quotes to surround the value.

Comment: @Raptor, I know it's not conventional but it works just fine. I use CentOS which is a Linux distribution with no issues. However, I do validate URLs for upper and lower case letters which admittedly is an unnessicary step, but remains a preference of mine. As long as performance is not lost (Disregarding micro-optimization), my syntax is as good as any.

Comment: With the exeption of the single quotes. You are spot on with that, as it can be left out. No need to do unnessicary comparisons when we know the value would be an integer, so thanks for that observation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i managed to get Reason to show but when status is entered from panel it uses `INSERT` not update so doesn't show latest ban reason as can be seen here: http://prntscr.com/kfq2pi
`gggggggg` is old ban reason, `Banned as a test` is new reason but it inserts over and over here is the code i tried using `UPDATE` but no avail

code: 
            `if ($status != $_POST['status']){
                $SQL = $odb -> prepare("UPDATE`users`SET`status`= :status WHERE`ID`= :id");
                $SQL -> execute(array(':status' => $_POST['status'], ':id' => $id));
                $status = htmlspecialchars($_POST['status']);
                $reason = htmlspecialchars($_POST['reason']);
                $SQLinsert = $odb -> prepare('INSERT INTO`bans`VALUES(:username, :reason)');
                $SQLinsert -> execute(array(':username' => $username, ':reason' => $reason));
                $update = true;
                $updateMsg = "Users status updated from {$status} to {$_POST['status']} with Reason: {$_POST['reason']} ";
            }`

Comment: Again: In order to be able to correctly help you, please provide 1) The connection creation code; 2) The code that you're using for error reporting; 3) The `CREATE TABLE` syntax. Additionally, give us the whole code of the php page, so that we figure out the semantically meaning of the values you are using. From the screenshot, it seems that your table structure is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Sql query:
SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = '1' AND username = :username